# Как исправить ошибку в npm "size is not defined"?

Tags: вёрстка, gulp, npm

Поставил модуль к gulp - gulp-processhtml, настроил папки, когда запускаю таск на сборку, выдает вот это [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить?
Код gulpfile.js - http://prntscr.com/kjcprn
Структура папок - http://prntscr.com/kjcr85

Comment: объявить функцию `size`.

Comment: ТС, скриншот это хорошо, но вставьте сообщение об ошибке текстом, это приветствуется.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, упустили объявление, типа `size = require('gulp-size')`,
 либо, если это плагин gulp-size у них в документации написано, что перед `gulp.src` создаётся переменная `size = require('gulp-size')({})` а уже в потоке выполняется все остальные манипуляции вместе с выводом.